# How to find out the date of the last Saturday in Linux shell script or python?

Tags: python, linux, shell

I have python script which i need to run daily for backups.
Now i need to find the date of last saturday because i need that in my script to get the backups i did on last saturdy. Suppose

on saturday i made this file

`weekly_user1_Jul-13-2013.sql`

I ned to get that name in script which i run daily. so for script running on saturday i need to get todays date , buif its on sunday then i need to get last saturday date.

how can i do that

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
$ date +"%b-%d-%Y" -d "last saturday"
Jul-13-2013
```

Comment: wow , didn't knew this is possible. what will happen on saturday

Comment: Note that this is a feature of GNU date; other `date` implementations may not support it.

Comment: I tried this code, got the below error :`echo $( date +"%b-%d-%Y" -d "last saturday")
date: illegal time format
usage: date [-jnu] [-d dst] [-r seconds] [-t west] [-v[+|-]val[ymwdHMS]] ... 
            [-f fmt date | [[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss]] [+format]

user@QD:~$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin15)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.`

Comment: OS X uses BSD date, not GNU date.

Answer (score 2):

In python script:

```
from datetime import date
from datetime import timedelta
today = date.today()
last_saturday = today - timedelta(days= (today.weekday() - 5) % 7)
```

Answer (score 1):

On Mac OS it would be:

```
$ date -v -sat +"%b-%d-%Y"
Mar-28-2015
```